# jQuery missing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

i've this:

```
            $('input#tags_watch').typeahead({
                highlight: true,
                autoselect: true
            },
            {
                source: names.ttAdapter(),
                displayKey: 'name',
                templates: {
                    suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
                      '<div id="{{id}}"><p class="repo-country">{{country}}</p>',
                      '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
                      '<p class="repo-city">{{city}} - {{ocupation}}</p></div>'
                    ].join(''))
                }
            });
```

it's allways returning an error:
**Uncaught Error: missing input**

i don't know why this happens, but the input exists!!!

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jhogLbg5/

Comment: What about making fiddle demo?

Comment: What input? What line is this error referring to? The selector on the first line?

Comment: formatting your code a bit

Comment: fiddle demo please. otherwise question make bit more decriptive. thanks

Comment: demo is there! jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-downloaded the handlebars.js, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is one annoying fact about V8. In most cases your JavaScript is broken in some way. For example missing a } or something like that.

Example given, this will yield "Unexpected missing input" too:

```
eval('[{"test": 4}') // notice the missing ]
```